# Homogeneous differential equation - clarification of definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

my professor has written this definition for a homogenous differential equation (with no more information): "A differential equation will be called homogenous if it is a homogenous function in $y$ (the unknown function) and its derivatives, but not for the independent variable x; $f(\lambda^k y^{(n)},\lambda^k y^{(n-1)},...,\lambda^k y, x)=f(y^{(n)}, y^{(n-1)},...,y,x)=0$"

could you explain how this definition is the same as saying that a differential equation is homogenous if $q(x)=0$, where $({a_n}y^{(n)}+{a_{n-1}}y^{(n-1)}+...+{a_0}y=q(x)$?

I thought of a possible explanation for why in my professor's definition it follows that $q(x)=0$ but I am not sure:

if $\lambda^k{a_n}y^{(n)}+\lambda^k{a_{n-1}}y^{(n-1)}+...+\lambda^k{a_0}y=q(x)$ and
${a_n}y^{(n)}+{a_{n-1}}y^{(n-1)}+...+{a_0}y=q(x)$,
we can subtract one from another and get $(\lambda^k-1){a_n}y^{(n)}+(\lambda^k-1){a_{n-1}}y^{(n-1)}+...+(\lambda^k-1){a_0}y=0$
and divide by $(\lambda^k-1)$ to get ${a_n}y^{(n)}+{a_{n-1}}y^{(n-1)}+...+{a_0}y=0$, and hence $q(x)=0$.

I believe this explanation is wrong, so I would be grateful if you could give a correct one.

Thank you in advance!